# python generator conversion

Tags: python, generator, networkx

i would like to know how to convert a generator with only one element into list.For example if f is a generator with one element,list(f) will raise "not iterable".how to solve this problem ?thanks in advance!

```
nx.adamic_adar_index(g, (0, 1))
list(nx.adamic_adar_index(g, (0, 1)))
```

this will raise TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable,the following is OK

```
nx.adamic_adar_index(g, [(0, 1),(2,3)])
list(nx.adamic_adar_index(g, [(0, 1),(2,3)]))
```

the result is [(0, 1, 2.3878841007006875), (2, 3, 0.9282626109897467)]

Comment: Please show the code you are having problems with, or a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) created from that code.

Comment: you're iterating over a list of tuples.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Isn't that error in `nx.adamic_adar_index(g, (0, 1))` itself?

Comment: Looks like `nx.adamic_adar_index`, whatever it is, is expecting a list of tuples. Try `nx.adamic_adar_index(g, [(0, 1)])`. In your first example, it would get `0`, which is an `int` and isn't iterable, instead of a `tuple`, which would have been.

Comment: It looks like the API wants a sequence of sequences. When you pass a sequence of integers it fails.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, your method works.In this way ,it not about generator with one element can't be converted into list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this: `[(0, 1),(2,3)]` is a list of two elements (each being a tuple of two elements) but  `(0, 1)` is a single element, could it be that you need to be a list of a single element, like `[(0, 1)]`?

I'd guess that:

```
list(nx.adamic_adar_index(g, [(0, 1)]))
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be it?

The generator must be evaluated to be listed. You can't list the generator itself.

```
>>> def g():
...     yield 1
...     
>>> list(g())
[1]
>>> list(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```